# Is it possible to access a struct member using a variable in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, struct

I've got a list of instances of the following `struct` called `payment_list`:

```
struct Payment: Codable {

    let id: Int
    let payment_hash: String
    let destination: String
    let msatoshi: Int
    let timestamp: Int
    let created_at: Int
    let status: String

    enum PaymentKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case payments
    }
}
```

I can access the members of each `struct` instance in the list in the following manner:

```
print(payment_list[0].id)        // 1 
print(payment_list[0].timestamp) // 1517083775
```

Is it possible to access those `struct` instance members using a variable to determine which member is being accessed? Something along the lines of:

```
var column = "id"
print(payment_list[0][column]) // 1
```

I've read about people using `NSObject` and `value(forKey key: String)`, but this is a `struct` so it can't inherit from `NSObject`. If it *was* an object I think it would look something like this:

```
var column = "id"
print(payment_list[0].value(forKey key: column)) // 1
```

Is this type of thing possible with `struct`?

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 added support for key paths, which allow to do something *similar* to what you want:

```
let keyPath: KeyPath<Payment, Int> = \Payment.id
var payment = Payment(id: 42)
let value = payment[keyPath: keyPath] // returns 42
```

A key path has two generic parameters: first the type it operates on (in your example `Payment`), and the type of the property it accesses (`Int`). Note that you'll have to specify the key path for every property you want to access.